# Defining C++ Interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following problem with defining an interface for a certain class. This is how my final classes look like:

```
class msg {
};

class statusmsg : public msg {
};

class valuemsg : public msg {
};
```

Now I need interfaces for the statusmsg and the valuemsg classes, but these interfaces also need to know the functions of the msg base class. I tried something like this.

Interfaces:

```
class i_msg {
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class i_statusmsg : public virtual i_msg {
    virtual void do_something_else() = 0;
};
```

Final class definitions:

```
class msg : public i_msg {
    void do_something() {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

class statusmsg : public i_statusmsg {
    void do_something_else() {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now I can't create an instance of statusmsg because the compiler tells me that do_something() is not implemented. Is there a way to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

### SOLUTION

Ok, I found a solution to this the problem is to place the virtual keyword correctly when inheriting. Here is the example code:

```
class i_msg {
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class i_statusmsg : public virtual i_msg {
public:
    virtual void do_something_else() = 0;
};

class msg : public virtual i_msg {
public:
    virtual void do_something() {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

class statusmsg : public i_statusmsg, public msg {
public:
    virtual void do_something_else() {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you expect `some_statusmsg->do_something()` to do?

Comment: You get it working by also implementing the inherited do_something() method.  *Required*.

Answer (score 1):

Your statusmsg isn't valid as it doesn't implement the pure virtual method `do_something()` from `i_msg`.

To get around this you can put an empty method declaration into `statusmsg` like so:

```
class statusmsg : public i_statusmsg {
    virtual void do_something_else();
    virtual void do_something() {};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have done, final classes should be:

```
class msg : public virtual i_msg {
    void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

class statusmsg : public /*virtual*/ i_statusmsg, public msg {
    void do_something_else() override {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

But it seems you have to rethink your design to avoid multiple inheritance.